# Filtering on a left join in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy

Using SQLalchemy I want to perform a left outer join and **filter out rows that DO have a match in the joined table**.

I'm sending push notifications, so I have a `Notification` table. This means I also have a `ExpiredDeviceId` table to store device_ids that are no longer valid. (I don't want to just delete the affected notifications as the user might later re-install the app, at which point the notifications should resume according to Apple's docs.)

```
CREATE TABLE Notification (device_id TEXT, time DATETIME);
CREATE TABLE ExpiredDeviceId (device_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, expiration_time DATETIME);
```

*Note: there may be multiple Notifications per device_id. There is no "Device" table for each device.*

So when doing `SELECT FROM Notification` I should filter accordingly. I can do it in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Notification 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ExpiredDeviceId 
    ON Notification.device_id = ExpiredDeviceId.device_id
WHERE expiration_time IS NULL
```

But how can I do it in SQLalchemy?

```
sess.query(
    Notification, 
    ExpiredDeviceId
).outerjoin(
    (ExpiredDeviceId, Notification.device_id == ExpiredDeviceId.device_id)
).filter(
    ???
)
```

Alternately I could do this with a `device_id NOT IN (SELECT device_id FROM ExpiredDeviceId)` clause, but that seems way less efficient.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you need to be pulling back the ExpiredDeviceId in a tuple? If you don't (i.e. you just care about live device_ids), then can't you just do:

```
sess.query(
    Notification
).outerjoin(
    (ExpiredDeviceId, Notification.device_id == ExpiredDeviceId.device_id)
).filter(
    ExpiredDeviceId.expiration_time == None
)
```

Comment: You're right. I incorrectly assumed that ExpiredDeviceId was actually an object reference, and that if there was no matching row ExpiredDeviceId itself would be None. However it's actually a class (table) name, and the expression is compiled to valid SQL. (Note that for the wording of my question, I need to check if it *IS* None, which also works.)

Comment: Ah good point, have edited my code excerpt to avoid confusion

Comment: `ExpiredDeviceId.expiration_time is None` won't work - it will always evaluate to False before being passed to .filter(), causing unexpected behavior (unexpected if you expect to read the query as you would read SQL). Use `==`.