# Exclude rows with no associated row in a joined table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to get instances (rows) of table `foo` that do not have a reference in `bar`

Table `foo`:

```
+----+-----+
| id | baz |
+----+-----+
|  1 |  23 |
|  2 |  56 |
|  3 |  45 |
|  4 |  78 |
+----+-----+
```

table `bar`:

```
+-----+--------+-----+
| id  | foo_id | zab |
+-----+--------+-----+
|  7  |      2 | s1  |
|  8  |      4 | s2  |
+-----+--------+-----+
```

The result of my query should be instances of `foo` as below:

```
+----+-----+
| id | baz |
+----+-----+
|  1 |  23 |
|  3 |  45 |
+----+-----+
```

Using the SQLAlchemy ORM, I have tried `join` and `outerjoin`, but the solution is still escaping me. Something tells me that the solution is easy and right in front of my face...

```
q = db.session.query(Foo).join(Baz, Baz.foo_id == Foo.id)

q = db.session.query(Foo).outerjoin(Baz, Baz.foo_id == Foo.id)
```

Comment: Please add your existing code to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering on a left join in SQLalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629684/filtering-on-a-left-join-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SQL query you're looking for is this:

```
SELECT foo.* FROM foo LEFT JOIN bar ON bar.foo_id = foo.id WHERE bar.foo_id IS NULL;
```

`LEFT JOIN`, as opposed to `INNER JOIN`, includes *all* rows from the 'left' table (i.e. the table specified in `FROM tblname`), even if they have no associated row in the 'right' table (the table specified in `JOIN tblname`). This means that rows that have no associated row in the right table will have `NULL` values instead:

```
foo.id | foo.baz | bar.id | bar.foo_id | bar.zab
-------+---------+--------+------------+--------
     1 |      23 |   NULL |       NULL |    NULL
     2 |      56 |      7 |          2 |      s1
```

So, filter for those rows that have a `NULL` in the right table's primary key (which can't be null in any other case, whereas other columns from the right table could be), and you get `foo` rows that have no associated `bar`.

In SQLAlchemy, that becomes this:

```
q = db.session.query(Foo).join(Bar, isouter=True).filter(Bar.id == None)
```

The `isouter=True` flag to `join` is [how you do a `LEFT JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43944701/3160466) with SQLAlchemy.